# how to edit project view in pycharm?

Tags: pycharm

is there any way to change font type/color/size of letters in project explorer?
`File | Settings | Editor | Font` changes font of editor window which is not what I am looking for.

Hope some1 shows me where in settings/xml-file I can adjust my font.

Comment: Either xml-file or `Menu->File->Settings` solution. Both ways are good.